# strcat append more than the assigned to array[ ]

Tags: c

I am learning about strings and in my last exercise happened something weird:

```
    char cadena5[]="Mensaje: ";
    char cadena6[50]="Mensaje: ";   //reserva espacio extra en memoria

    char cadena7[]="Programar en Objective C es facil";


    NSLog(@"La logitud de cadena5 es: %li", strlen(cadena5) );
    NSLog(@"La logitud de cadena6 es: %li", strlen(cadena6) );
    NSLog(@"La logitud de cadena7 es: %li", strlen(cadena7) );

    strcat(cadena5, cadena7);
    NSLog(@"strcat %s", cadena5);
```

My output shows the complete string appended but in my book says that xcode will complain 'cause there's no enough free space to append in "cadena5" and recommends to use "cadena6" instead.

```
2014-05-16 23:43:02.518 Array de chars[3027:303] La logitud de cadena5 es: 9
2014-05-16 23:43:02.518 Array de chars[3027:303] La logitud de cadena6 es: 9
2014-05-16 23:43:02.519 Array de chars[3027:303] La logitud de cadena7 es: 33
2014-05-16 23:43:02.520 Array de chars[3027:303] strcat Mensaje: Programar en Objective C es facil
```

Looking to the tutorial should appear a "signal SIGABRT" thread...
What happened? is this normal?

Comment: When you access memory that you are not supposed to, anything can happen -- including normal run of the program. The behavior after that is not predictable.

Comment: Undefined behaviour includes the possibility that the code will seem to work. You might print out (`NSLog`) `cadena6` after the `strcat()` too; there's a chance it may have been overwritten by the concatenation.  Sometimes, you get (un)lucky because bad code appears to work and doesn't cause a crash.

Comment: welcome to the world of undefined behavior. This is an example of the worst kind; it works but should not. It will fail on a mission critical system in the middle of the night.

Comment: @RSahuL Check the spec again: The behavior _before_ that is _also_ unpredictable.

Comment: Undefined behaviors are pretty scary :(

Comment: @pedaleo does it work, I mean crash, if you move the code to a function, like `void f() { char cad1[]..... }` and call that from `main`?

Comment: @alain that worked now my code "crash", well not crash but the output is correct, Thanks.

Comment: @pedaleo a unique opportunity to say: I'm happy it crashes :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By all rights, the program deserved to receive a SEGFALT and worse.  But it got lucky and had memory where it needed to be.

In a more general case, it might have experienced "unexplained" changes to other variables—had there been a lot of other variables in the right place in memory.

You can make this program work portably and correctly with a very minor change:

```
 char cad1[100] = "Hola ";
```

This over-allocates the destination string and allows for appending a limited amount of text.

Comment: Quote: "What happened? is this normal?"

Comment: @MooingDuck:  Quite right.  I have amended my answer.

Comment: Thanks is a good workaround, the thing that scares me is what happens if one day I don't see this kind of "undefined behavior"

I got the idea, thanks again to everyone,but how can I close/resolve that post?

Answer (score -1):

Variables are pushed onto the stack in the order they appear in a function. When something is pushed, the stack pointer is decreased by the amount of memory needed, and then the object is written to that location.

If your program doesn't crash, you probably have defined variables before `cadena5`. If you have

```
char A[10];
char B[10];
```

you can "safely" write 20 chars into `B`, the 10 chars that don't fit into `B` are "just" overwriting `A`.

This is already bad, but it gets worse: At some point you will be overwriting the return address, and that's when the crash becomes inevitable.

So if you want the crash, just remove any variable definition before `cadena5`.

Edit: This applies to C, I don't know how it is in Objective-C.

Edit2: This is not guaranteed, compilers are free to arrange the variables in any order on the stack, see the comments.

Comment: **Do not** depend on this behavior.  Compilers can arrange variables on the stack in any order they want.  "Large" variables might not be on the stack at all.

Comment: @wallyk That's interesting, thanks. Does this apply to C or to Objective-C?

Comment: @alain I tried it in a new project, just with two variables and still happens... I tried also to append a good string into an array[1] and still working... undefined behaviors are the worst thing ever.

Comment: @alain:  It applies to all languages I know of (about 35).

Comment: @wallyk: It doesn't apply to most languages that I know of, only a few C based languages have pointers that make this possible.  It's not possible in Fortran, Java, C#, Python, Perl, Haskell, Lisp, BrainF***, PHP, javascript, Basic...  To my knowledge it's only possible in C, C++, Obj-C, Obj-C++, and D.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  It is quite possible in FORTRAN 77:  I have accidentally changed the constant `1` to `2` by carelessly altering a parameter which was intended to be a variable.  Indeed, it is more difficult in scripting languages but I bet I can do it in Perl and Lisp.

Comment: @all it's a wiki now, do you want to improve the answer?

Comment: @wallyk: I was specifically referring to writing past the end of an array, I don't think Fortran77 could do that.  Interpreted as "undefined behavior", then yes, pretty much every language has some undefined behaviors.

Comment: Variables are **not** guarenteed to be pushed onto the stack in the order they appear in a function.  This answer is just wrong.

Comment: @GoodPerson In MSVC++, they are, most of the time, at least.

Comment: @alain: for all versions? current, future, and past? With all compiler options? will you never use another compiler? Do you want your code to depend that?

Comment: @GoodPerson No, I will never want my code to depend on that ;-). I checked C++ 2010, and I think it was this way in past versions, too.